# Read file and pipe it to awk does not print the expected results

Tags: bash, awk

If I have file `test.txt` contains 3 lines;

```
1  
2   
3
```

If I run

`cat test.txt| while read a ; do awk  -v c=$a '{print c}' ;done`

It will print these values.

```
1  
1
```

But if I run

`cat test.txt|  awk '{a=$0; print a}'`
It will behave as expected.

```
1  
2   
3
```

Any explanation?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you be by "behave as expected".  Both code samples behave exactly as expected.

Comment: Ok, I am thinking that `cat test.txt| while read a ; do awk  -v c=$a '{print c}' ;done`. this code should print also 1 2 3.  Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first version `awk` is not getting stdin as you intended.

Copying from the comment by @William Purcell: "The read command reads the first line of input, and awk reads the next 2 (the 2 and the 3). That's why you see two lines of output."

For the next two lines you have initialized `c` variable with `1` (from first read).

If you wrap your statement in `BEGIN` block it will work as intended.

```
$ seq 3 | while IFS= read -r a; do awk -v c="$a" 'BEGIN{print c}'; done
```

however, that's rather inefficient way of doing things.

Comment: Not quite.  The `read` command reads the first line of input, and `awk` reads the next 2 (the 2 and the 3).  That's why you see two lines of output.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I don't think so. If it read the next two lines of input, the read operation would reach EOF and the loop would end, meaning the output would only be a single 0.

Comment: @CHess There is only 1 iteration of the loop.  In that single iteration of the loop, `awk` reads 2 lines of input and generates one line of output for each line that it reads.

Comment: That is, `awk` first reads the line "2", and then prints the value of the variable `c`, which is "1".  Then it reads "3" and prints "1" again.

Answer (score 0):

Let `awk`read from the variable that has been set, not from stdin.

```
seq 3 | while IFS= read -r a; do awk '{print}' <<<"$a"; done
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works besides what @karakfa suggested.

Comment: But you basically never want to run Awk inside a `while read` loop. Just let Awk read the file; that's what it was designed for.

Comment: @triplee I know. OP also posted `cat test.txt|  awk '{a=$0; print a}'` (better `awk '{a=$0; print a}' test.txt`), therefor I hope it is only a simplified version of his real problem and not intended as the intended approach.

Comment: Thanks @Walter A. Actually this just simplified version of the main issue.